# Cassandra Invalid Query: Some cluster keys are missing

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra 3.0.

My table was created with this query, but when I try to insert data into the table, I get the error: 'Some cluster keys are missing: created'

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE db.feed (
    action_object_id int,
    owner_id int,
    created timeuuid,
    action_object text,
    action_object_type int,
    actor text,
    feed_type text,
    target text,
    target_type int,
    verb text,
    PRIMARY KEY (action_object_id, owner_id, created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (owner_id ASC, created ASC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to provide values for all the primary keys. *action_object_id, owner_id, created* must have to be mentioned in your insert query. 
Ex: insert into db.feed(action_object_id, owner_id, created, ...) values (?,?,?,...). And you cannot provide **NULL** values for primary keys. *created* cannot be null.

Comment: If you found this helpful and figure out the problem, then please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks... Was helpful